# What's are the benefits of different sourdough starter consistencies?

Tags: baking, bread, sourdough, sourdough-starter

Is there any real differences between keeping a sourdough starter at a thick dough like consistency compared to a more watery consistency? Aside from the general thoughts of thicker being easier to keep.

Comment: Please refer to my answer in this [question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/39876/how-does-hydration-of-a-sourdough-affect-baking-features/40012#40012), where I covered, among other things, the different things you can do to a sourdough and their effects.

Answer (score 4):

Since a starter is actually a symbiotic mixture of microorganisms, factors like hydration level can change the balance of bacteria and yeasts. Depending on which organisms are favored, it can change the flavor, gas production, etc. They're not necessarily "benefits", but different consistencies can definitely produce different starters. The biggest and most consistent difference that I can think of would be that wetter starters are usually more active.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So would semi regularly changing the consistency weaken a starter, or are the various yeasts quite adaptable?

Comment: @Corsara They're pretty adaptable. You won't get the full effect of the different consistency until you've had it that way through several feedings, but it won't hurt it to change it.