# Remedy a sourdough which used milled red winter wheat

Tags: sourdough, wheat, sourdough-starter

I followed a sourdough recipe that said to use bread flour, I thought a hard red winter wheat ran through our grain mill would suffice if I sifted out the bran... Apparently not. Is there any way to salvage this? The bread just is not wanting to rise at all. I have about 6 cups of wheat and 4 days of work invested in this dough. The dough started out bubbly with a rye base, but after adding the milled winter wheat it slowly began to lose its bubbles.  Maybe there is still microscopic wheat bran that the sifter didn't get... I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: Isn't a 4 day old sourdough awfully young to be baking with at all? I wouldn't have expected it to have established a solid culture.

Comment: Your situation isn't entirely clear from the question. But assuming you've created a starter from scratch, I agree with rumtscho. Have a look at [my answer to a similar question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/33747/15018). There will be a period of rapid growth and lots of bubbles anywhere from day 1 to 3. After that, the starter will often become less active for a while. That's because the initial activity is usually due to bacteria growth--not yeast--and those kind of bacteria can't survive anymore as the starter becomes acidic. Type of wheat and bran should NOT be the problem here.